# Disallowing http communication

Tags: apache-2.4, https, http, google-cloud-platform

I am running an Ubuntu instance on GCP with apache2 and php 7.
More so, I am using CloudFlare as my SSL certificate provider.

In GCP, if I configure "allow http and https", the website works both for http and https. Though I have to specifically add the https prefix to domain, so that it will work securely.

But, if I disallow the http in GCP, and allow only https, I am unable to enter my website whatsoever, even with adding the https prefix.

Is there any configuration I am missing in GCP or Apache2?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: I found a partial workaround solution via Cloudflare, where there's an option to redirect all http to https via their configuration panel. Though I guess there might be a solution to my issue via GCP as well, that I don't know of yet

Comment: HSTS Preload would help, as would using an `.app` domain

Answer (score 1):

Try to simple add redirection rule in `apache` configuration for 
listen on `port 80`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        Redirect permanent / https://your_domain_name.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache allows you to create redirections which you can use to suit your needs:

Temporary redirect with Redirect

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain1.com
    Redirect / http://www.domain2.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain2.com
    . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

Temporary redirects with RedirectMatch

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain1.com
    RedirectMatch ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain2.com
    . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

Permanent redirects

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain1.com
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com    
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*)$ http://domain2.com/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

Further information can be found in this [documentation link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache)